# vega-lite/altair: insert partially italics font in text

Tags: fonts, altair, vega-lite

I am working with Vega-Lite/Altair diagrams and I am having trouble including only one word in italics within a title. I have tried using the following methods but they do not work:

- `...).properties(title=['text <i>italic text</> other text'])`
- `...).properties(title=['text {italic}italic{/italic} other text'])`

What is the correct and simple solution for formatting only one word in italics within a title?